# return an array from jQuery ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am reading an rss file with jquery ajax function in the success i create the array function `mycarousel_itemList` and fill it with items using push. I want to use this array in a function that I created then, but I get the error:

> `mycarousel_itemList` is not defined

What's going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rss = 'http://search.issuu.com/userxxx/docs/recent.rss';
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'js/issuuGallery/proxy.php?url='+rss,
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(xml) {
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.setAttribute('id', 'issuu-gallery');
    ul.setAttribute('class', 'overview');

    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
        var mycarousel_itemList = [];
        var id = $(this).find('[name="documentId"]').attr('value');
        var src = 'http://image.issuu.com/'+id+'/jpg/page_1_thumb_small.jpg';
        mycarousel_itemList.push(src);
        console.log(mycarousel_itemList);
    });
}
});
function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
{

for (var i = carousel.first; i <= carousel.last; i++) {
    if (carousel.has(i)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (i > mycarousel_itemList.length) {
        break;
    }

    carousel.add(i, mycarousel_getItemHTML(mycarousel_itemList[i-1]));
}
   };

/**
 * Item html creation helper.
 */
function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item)
{
return '<img src="' + item.url + '" width="75" height="75" alt="' + item.url + '" />';
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
    itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback}
});
});
```

Comment: It looks like in the jQuery(document).ready call you are referencing the mycarousel_itemList to try to calculate the size, but I don't think that the variable is in scope there. Do you know the specific line number that is causing the error?

Comment: `mycarousel_itemList` is a local variable that is only available inside of your .each() loop. Try to omit the "var" keyword. But even worse: You try to access mycarousel_itemList before the ajax call even finishes ... you will have to reconsider your program flow.

Comment: The error is in the second if of the function 'mycarousel_itemLoadCallback'. I dont konw how to make the array is available in the other functions outside the success function of ajax. This is my problem

Comment: How reconsider my program flow @devnull69?

Comment: Generally: Every action that depends on the result of an asynchronous request should be executed in (or called from) the callback of the request. So you'll have to move everything that depends on the result of the request into the success callback. This is where mycarousel_itemList is available

Comment: is there anyway to make the array available for other functions? @devnull69

Comment: you could make the array a global variable by omitting the "var" keyword (as mentioned above). But then you will have to take care of the timing. The array will only be defined after the Ajax request finished. "After" is not related to the code lines but rather to the time of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're just loading the rss feed once then creating a carousel with the result. If so, this is easy to fix.

1. Look for this line:

   ```
   var mycarousel_itemList = [];
   ```

   That is creating a local variable inside the ajax success callback. What you'll want to do is make it global and move it to the top (make it the very first line inside the < script> tag).
2. Move the $.ajax call to inside the document ready callback.
3. Find the following jcarousel code:

   ```
   jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
       size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
       itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback}
   });
   ```

   Move it to inside the $.ajax callback as the last thing in the callback.

Your final code should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h35VQ/